# Can I set extra columns at pandas read_table() to avoid CParserError?

Tags: python, python-3.x, parsing, pandas, dataframe

I have the following file which I try to import into a pandas dataframe with Python 3.4.5:

```
filename = "fname.dat"
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_table(filename)
```

However, due to how the data is formatted (i.e. some rows have 22 columns, others 23), I get the following error:

```
pandas.parser.CParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 22 fields in line 13,  saw 23
```

This problem exists in many lines, so skipping lines a priori doesn't quite make sense to me. One could use the parameter `error_bad_lines=False`, i.e.

```
df = pd.read_table(filename, error_bad_lines=False)
```

but this isn't a good solution, as this causes the "problem rows" to be skipped.

For `fname.dat`, this means skipping thousands of lines.

Can't I allocate memory at `pandas.read_table()` for an empty column which is used if there are 23 columns in a row instead of 22? How does this affect the other rows?

Should I somehow direct pandas to say "if non-existent, skip"?

Comment: Try using python csv reader to read this file.

Comment: @Merlin Using `pandas.read_csv()` results in the same error

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html  This not pandas read_csv.

Comment: @Merlin How does one use `csv.reader()` to import into a pandas dataframe?